# Javascript Inheritance Explanation

Tags: javascript, inheritance, logic, prototype

I am trying to understand the inheritance and prototype logic of the JS. So I have a question.

To demonstrate it I wrote that kind of code...

```
class Boat {
 constructor() {
 
 }
}

class SpeedBoat {
 constructor() {
   new Boat();
 }
}


class Yatch {
  constructor() {
     new Boat()
  }
}

const yatch = new Yatch()
const speedBoat = new SpeedBoat()
const boat = new Boat()

console.log(yatch instanceof Boat)
console.log(speedBoat instanceof SpeedBoat)
console.log(boat instanceof Boat)
```

'''

The console results are;

false
true
true

I will be appreciate to anyone who can explain this results in detail. Thank you.

Comment: It’s not clear where you got the idea that this way of creating “inheritance” is at all correct; have you reviewed the *Inheritance* section of [MDN’s page on Classes in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Classes_in_JavaScript) (or any other authoritative source)? You should be using the `extends` keyword and `super` builtin to get what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last two console logs give you `true` because

- `speedBoat` instance is created from `SpeedBoat` class => `speedBoat = new SpeedBoat()`
- Similarly, `boat` instance is created from `Boat` class => `boat = new Boat()`

The fist one gives you `false` because

`yatch` instance is created from `Yatch` class => `yatch = new Yatch()` and you're checking if this `yatch` instance is an instance of `Boat` class which is **NOT TRUE**

**Why inheritance is not working for you when you do -  console.log(yatch instanceof Boat)**

- Inheritance is the concept where Child class (Yatch in this case) is getting all its properties and methods from the parent class Boat. But that's not happening in your case as you're not inheriting it properly.
- In your `Yatch` classes' constructor (and all other constructors), you're defining like this:

The below code doesn't work

```
class Yatch {
  constructor() {
     new Boat() // this line is creating object/instance of Boat class and this object is not pointing to any variable and hence will be garbage collected (will be removed from the memory)
  }
}
```

**How to define inheritance?**

You need to use **extends** keyword in the Child class (Yatch) and tell which should be the parent class (Boat) like this

```
class Yatch extends Boat{
  super() { // this super keyword calls the constructor of parent (Boat class)
     new Boat()
  }
}
```

Modified working code - https://codepen.io/sandeep194920-the-flexboxer/pen/bGvaoyW?editors=1111

Comment: Hello Sandeep, I got the idea that you are mentioned. I believe I already familiar with the inheritance concept in OO languages. The question is asked to me with a claim that saying there is a tricky part because of the difference in javascript. That's why I asked here because I couldn't see any other answer without your's.

Comment: Javascript ES6 classes work similarly to other languages. But the underlying concept is all functions on which prototypal inheritance can be applied. You can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: Reference - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnME98ckDbQ

Answer (score 0):

`speedboat` and `boat` are literally instances of the `SpeedBoat` and `Boat` classes respectively, which inheritance does not come into play.

You might be wondering why the `Yatch` class isn't inherited from the `Boat` class, hence why `yatch` isn't an instance of the `Boat` class. It's missing the `extends` keyword, which formally states that `Yatch` is inherited from the `Boat` class.

```js
class Yatch extends Boat{
}
```

Will functionally do the same with the inheritance included.